# Cannot read property 'match' of null

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match incoming value and only allow alphanumeric characters and null in Javascript.
but when I match/exec in console even it throws errors.

```
var code = null;
if(code.match(/[-[\]{}()*+?._\\^$|#]+/) || !code.match(/^[a-z0-9\0]+/){
     console.log('It works');
}
```

errors is here.
 ***Cannot read property 'match' of null***

Comment: Well...you're trying to call a method on `null`. The error message is quite clear that you can't do that. What's the question...? What is your goal calling methods on `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call methods on `null`, as the error message is telling you.

[`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) is a method of regular expression objects. You call it on a regular expression, and pass in a string for the expression to run against. So for instance, `result = /[-[\]{}()*+?._\\^$|#]+/.exec(someString)`.

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is sort of the converse: You call it on a string and pass in a regular expression, and again, the regular expression is run against the string (slightly differently, see the links for details): For instance: `result = someString.match(/[-[\]{}()*+?._\\^$|#]+/)`

But note that in both cases, we have two things: A regular expression, and a string. `null` is neither of those things. What's missing in your question's code is a string to work with.

Answer (score 0):

using typeof code to detect if code is not null and string, and use \w+ to match alphanumeric.

```
var code = ... // null or string;
if (((typeof code) === 'string')) && code.match(/\w+/)) {
    // TODO: it works
}
```